# compile a java program as different user

Tags: java, command-line, compiling

I am able to login as a different user using a shell script in Ubuntu, but I want to run a Java program in that user, but it halts there...

for example:

1. login as a guest user with limited permission
2. compile HelloWorld.java
3. java HelloWorld.java

The script I wrote:

```
USER=sameek
su $USER
javac HelloWorld.java echo compiled
```

Kindly show me a path to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your script is that the `su $USER` line invokes a subshell and so the next command doesn't execute until that subshell is exited.

You probably want to do something more like:

```
USER=sameek
USERCMDS=/tmp/usercommands.$$
echo "JAVA_HOME=..." >>$USERCMDS
echo "PATH=\${JAVA_HOME}:\$PATH" >> $USERCMDS
echo "javac HelloWorld.java" >> $USERCMDS
chmod a+x $USERCMDS
su $USER -c $USERCMDS
```

Comment: thank you sir but when i tried to run the script then i says javac command not found. i have set all the environment variables also added the java path in login.def i think its again reseting the path.